# As a student, he ... / When he was a student, he

Tags: difference

> As a student, he ...

> When he was a student, he ...

If I understand right, there is no difference in meaning between the sentences except the phrase "as a student" doesn't contain time reference. Am I right?

Comment: Depending on the verb tense, _as a student_ could mean either _when he was a student_ or _because he is a student_.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, Does it mean that "as a student" can't be used with future tense? For example, "As a student, he will do that quicker."

Comment: _As a student (because he is one), he will receive a discount on purchases from this store._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two phrases do not mean the same thing, even though they are sometimes both correct in the same contexts, and sentences with either phrase can have similar enough meanings to be equivalent.

"*When he was a student*" refers to **the time** he spent as a student.

"*As a student*" means "***in his capacity*** as a student".

So these two sentences are roughly the same:

> When he was a student, he worked hard.
> As a student, he worked hard.

But these pairs of sentences are not the same:

> When he was a student, he was adequate. (*He was adequate **at something** during the time he was a student.*)
> As a student, he was adequate. (*He was **an adequate student**.*)

> When he was a student, his mother died. (*His mother died during the time he was a student*.)
> As a student, his mother died. (*His mother died when **she** was a student*.)

Comment: What do you mean by "the **final** sentences"?

Comment: Honestly, I don't see the difference in usage between your first and second example. "When he was a student, he worked hard." - Reading that I think he could work hard at his job. "When he was a student, he was adequate." - Here could be the same thing. Are you agree?

Comment: @Sergei I've edited my first paragraph. Lemme know if it's easier to understand now.

Comment: @Sergei Yes, I agree that in both examples, the second part of the sentence could refer to something other than his capacity as a student. In my first example, however, unless the context mentioned that he had a job, the first sentence would be understood to mean the same as the second. It's like the sentence "*He was a hard-working student*" *could* be naively read to mean he worked hard *at his job* while he was a student, but the only natural reading of that sentence or the sentences in my first example is: "*He worked hard **at his studies** when he was a student*".

Answer (score 1):

> As a student, he was conscientious.
> He was a conscientious student.
> When he was a student, he was conscientious.

have the same meaning (even though they might allude to different ideas).

The phrase "as a student" doesn't contain a time reference. The verb provides it.

Since it doesn't include time, you can use it with any tense (including the future):

> As a mother, she will always love him.